# NFS Server IPv6 best practices?

Tags: networking, security, ipv6, nfs

I have a NFS server that only has exports for 10.0.0.0/16. I'm enabling IPv6 on all my network (homelab network), and want to switch all services to prefer ipv6 if possible.

With that being said, what are some best practices to follow with NFS using IPv6 in terms of security and accesibility?

Or does it all translate to ipv6, by simply specifying the share as something like `aaaa:aaaa:aaaa:aaaa::/64` as the nfs export?

Comment: Are you looking for something specfic? IPv6 is just IPv6. There's nothing special about it "in terms of security and accessibility".